# Is there a way to group the columns based on a different column in the same table for a dropdown with grouped options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to display a dropdown whose values should be displayed in the order of different fields in the same table.

i.e, table "users" has `id`, `category`, `name`, and `description`.

I need to display a select menu for users's name and those values should be grouped by category. I used `grouped_collection_select` to achieve this, but no luck since those fields are present in the same table.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :user_id %>
  <%= form.grouped_collection_select :user_id, Something.order(:category), User.order(:name), :category, :id, :name %>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's look at the doc first: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select

```rb
grouped_collection_select(object, method, collection, group_method, group_label_method, option_key_method, option_value_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

and an example:

```rb
grouped_collection_select(:city, :country_id, @continents, :countries, :name, :id, :name)
```

to be honest I don't quite get that method myself, so let's use `grouped_options_for_select`.

```rb
f.select :name, grouped_options_for_select(User.all.group_by(&:category))
```

this assume you have a `category` attribute on your model.

Comment: <optgroup label="Ethernet Failure">
<option value="#<Discrepancy:0x000000001091c318>">#&lt;Discrepancy:0x000000001091c318&gt;</option>
</optgroup>
This the o/p I am getting.
It should not display optgroup value as of one of the option and also option value gets displayed with "Object" instead of its value

Comment: oh that's because I have `to_s`, you may be better off writing the optgroup / option manually (e.g. you would need to pass a `{ disabled: true }` in the nested array you would be creating with `grouped_options_for_select`).

Comment: How do I get the value of the object in views itself?

Comment: I recommend trying it out in rails console and trying to get those array correctly nested if you are going the `grouped_options_for_select` route. this is the structure you are trying to get to: `[["g1", [["n1", "v1"], ["n2", "v2"]]], ["g2", [["n3", "v3"], ["n4", "v4"]]]]`, so for instance `Account.all.group_by(&:kind).map { |key, values| [[key, { disabled: true }], values.map { |v| [v.to_s, v.id] }] }` works (grouping the accounts by kind, with selection of groups disabled and displays the account names with id as the values)

Comment: I am facing one more issue with the drop down which has same values.  
Account table data 
 id :1category:test, name : testing
id : 2 , category : test, name :testing123
id: 3 , category : demo , name : demo
<%= form.collection_select :account_id, Account.group(:category), :id, :category, { include_blank: "" } %>
<option value =1> test</option>
<option value = 3> demo </option>It works fine in "New Form" , Unfortunately "edit form " will  not find all id's and therfore value will not get retained.
Can you plz let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: looks like you can pass a `selected` key to `collection_select`: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

Comment: <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :discrepancy_id, 'Failure Category' %>
    <%= form.collection_select :discrepancy_id, Discrepancy.group(:category), :id, :category, {:selected => Discrepancy.all.select('id').where("category LIKE 'AVOD%'").first}, :class => 'failure-category', :required => true%>
  </div>
selected is not working but the query (Discrepancy.all.select('id').where("category LIKE 'AVOD%'").first ) works in rails console

Comment: How to add :disabled attribute if one of the column is archieved? Account.all.group_by(&:kind).map { |key, values| [[key, { disabled: true }], values.map { |v| [v.to_s, v.id] }] }  i.e if v.archival_id.nil? in grouped_options_for_select